# Proof of conformal mappings onto polygons (Stein)

Tags: complex-analysis, reflection

Recently I am reading Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* and I find a great difficulty in understanding the proof of theorem 4.6 in Chapter 8 (p.242-244), which talks about conformal mappings onto polygons.

It first introduces the function $h_k$ and shows that it can be analytically continuous to an infinite strip. I understand that why $h_k'\ne 0$ but I don't know why that 
$$\frac{F''(z)}{F'(z)}=\frac{-\beta_k}{z-A_k}+E_K(z)$$

I don't know why this expression is true and also don't understand the meaning of $\frac{F''(z)}{F'(z)}$ for $\text{Im}(z)<0$, since only $h_k$ is defined for $\text{Im}z<0$ but not $F$ (if I define $F=h_k^{\alpha_k}+a_k$, will it be the same $F$ as the one I will discuss in the next paragraph?). Here I assume $$h_k(z)=e^{i\theta}\overline{h_k(\overline z)}\hspace{.5in} \text{for}\hspace{.1in}\text{Im}(z)>0.$$

Secondly, in the next page (p.244), the writer is going to proof that $F$ is holomorphic outside a large circle so is at the infinity. I don't really understand what he means, only have an idea: since a polygon is bounded, any $\text{Im}z<0$ can correspond to a $\bar z$ which $F(z)$ can be defined by reflecting $F(\bar z)$ along an edge of the polygon. I think I miss something because according to this, $F$ can be extend to become an entire function, which seems that I am wrong.

Can anyone please help me understand the proof of this theorem?

Answer (score 0):

I am also reading this book and here is my understanding about the first question:

The continuation of a homorphic function is unique in the sense that two holomorphic funtion corresponding on some non-empty open subset are the same function.

Here is what Stein said in Chapter 2:

> **Corollary 4.9** Suppose $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a region $\Omega$ and $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z$ in some non-empty open subset on $\Omega$ (or more generally for $z$ in some sequence of distinct points with limit point in $\Omega$.) Then $f(z) = g(z)$ throughout $\Omega$.
>
> Suppose we are given a pair of functions $f$ and $F$ analytic in regions $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$, respectively, with $\Omega \subset \Omega'$. If the two functions agree on the smaller set $\Omega$, we say that $F$ is an **analytic continuation** of $f$ into the region $\Omega'$, The corollary then guarantees that there can be only one such analytic continuation, since $F$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

We define $F$ for $\mathrm{Im}(z) < 0$ by $F = h_{k}^{\alpha_{k}} + a_{k}$ and then we can get the **unique** continuation of $F$ on $\{ z \mid A_{k-1} < \mathrm{Re}(z) < A_{k + 1} \}$.

However I am also confused about the second assertion that

> $F$ is continuable in the exterior of a disc $|z| \leq R$, for large $R$.

I have no idea what's the connection with reflection principle. Should we find the continuation of $F$ on the disc first? If so, we need to verify the continuation we made above is holomorphic on the line $\{z\mid \mathrm{Re}(z) = A_{k},\ 1 \leq k \leq n\}$. If that's possible, we have already get an entire function and there is no need to make furthur continuation.

Hope more answers would come to help.